# What are the cold cranking amps required to start Jaguar S type 3l petrol engine

Tags: battery, cold-start, jaguar, s-type

I'm trying to find the typical* cold cranking amps required to start a Jaguar S-type 3 litre v6 petrol engine (UK) so that I can be more informed when I research batteries, boosters, chargers etc. I've tried searching for the answer to this question online to no avail.

* I know it might vary, so I am looking to get an approximation, an idea.  Not an exact figure. Some further info to narrow it down...

- Weather:  Cold but not freezing (let's say 10 °C).
- Time since last start - typcially 1 week (but sometimes won't start after a short journey has taken place and the car has been parked, then left for half an hour, this after about a week of no driving) - The car gets used on weekends
- Amount of charge in battery - Not dead, but not enough to start by itself.

Comment: Are you actually trying to find out the CCA for starting, or what the standard CCA battery size is? The amount required to start any vehicle is going to be different depending on the weather, how long its been since the vehicle was started, etc. You also need to worry about reserve capacity. There are a lot of things to think about.

Comment: I'm looking for the CCA for starting.  THe reason I included the word 'typical' is because I know it might vary.

Comment: Then there's no real way to answer your question.

Comment: Why is that?   abc

Comment: As I stated, there are too many variables. It's going to be different at any given time. If it's 0°C and the car has sat for two weeks, it's going to take a huge amount more Amps to start a car than if it is 32°C and you started it earlier in the day. It's actually Amps which would start the car, not CCA. CCA is the amount of Amps available at 0°F (IIRC) in a given battery.

Comment: I've added some details. I'm just trying to get an approximation or average.  How hard can that be??

Comment: Why not use the stock battery figure in your case? It should be chosen to have a safe CCA rating.

Comment: In cold countries there are a lot of batteries for cold weather claiming so many more amps delivered when cold. Every year theres something better, because of technology or even just marketing (specially where its -20C for more than a few months). There isnt a  "standard". The starter can draw 400A (just ballpark, it really depends from so many factors...) in a cold day and batteries normally will be able to deliver that. Then if your battery is old, damaged, tired, not charged and there are a bunch of other electronics to feed at the same time it wont give what it did when old.

Comment: Unless the condition of your battery show that is the actual problem do not try to use a new one as a band-aid for bad connections or other things draining it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended battery for a 2000* Jaguar S-type 3.0 is a 019, which has 800CCA and a capacity of 100Ah.

*Randomly chosen as you didn't specify a year.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm hoping the CCA of the recommended battery is deliberately more than a bit higher than what's required to start the engine.  The reason being I ened up buying quite a beefy battery pack,  and since discovered that its CCA is about 600. (I misunderstood the jargon and thought the 'peak amps' 1600 was the CCA.  So far I haven't had to use it.

Comment: @MrVimes if it fits in the engine bay, then a bigger battery is fine.  It will weigh more is the only real drawback, but will give more years of service overall.